# DB2 Query optimization

Tags: sql, database, query-optimization

All ,
Need help in optimizing a query :

There are two tables with below fields:

> Table 1  AdminId Policy Locationid CreateTimestamp
>
> Table 2 AdminId Policy CreateTimestamp Detail1 Detail2 . Detail50

Table 2 is a big table will lots of data. For every rec in Table1 there can be thousands of rows in Table2. 
Requirement is to get the count last one year data from table 2 which have location = NY .
I wrote below query but its not optimized and m not able to run it.
Please suggest how to optimize this query. Thanks in advance!

```
Select count(*) from Table2 T2 , Table1 T1 where T1.adminId = T2.adminId and 
T1.policy = T2.policy and T1.location like ('℅NY℅') and 
T2.createTimestamp > ( current Timestamp - 1 year)
```

Comment: Do you really have multiple values stored in location? IS that why you need a wildcard?

Comment: Yes , the locationid is a 15 byte field and NY comes somewhere in middle so I have to use wildcard..

Answer (score 0):

You should first modifying your query to use ANSI style explicit JOIN syntax like

```
Select count(*) from Table2 T2 
JOIN Table1 T1 
ON T1.adminId = T2.adminId 
and T1.policy = T2.policy 
where T1.location like ('℅NY℅') 
and T2.createTimestamp > ( current Timestamp - 1 year)
```

Also make sure you have an index created on all the  columns involved in `JOIN ON` condition and `WHERE` condition for both tables.

Comment: Do you actually think there's a different plan just because of old vs. new join?

Comment: While I agree whole-heartedly that old style implicit joins should never be used, this will not solve the performance issue.

Comment: If he's having a performance issue with a single join then he's got bigger issues than getting the count for one simple query.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely your problem:

```
and T1.location like ('℅NY℅')
```

In most databases this type of construction does not allow you to use the indexes and thus the query cannot perform well.

If you do not have multiple locations in the field, then remove the wildcards as unnecessary. If you have them, then you need to change your data model to put that data properly in a related table. NEVER store comma (or other delimiter) delimited list in a field in a database.

If you cannot change the data model the best you can do is to write a function to split the data into some type of temporary table and then join to that. IN Sql Server, I would suggest you look up fn_split through Google to get an idea as to how to do that. I am not familiar with how you would do that sort of thing in DB2, but there is probably a similar function floating around the internet to start from.

Comment: Actually , it is necessary to use a wild card for location as I have a 15 byte locationid and 'NY' comes somewhere in between. Is it the reason why the query is taking long time to execute? It is not at all executing in production. I work on mainframes and I m currently using QMF to execute this query.If it runs fine then I'll include this in my code. Appreciate all your help! :-)

Comment: In most databases, wildcards at teh start of a where condition mean that indexes cannot be used. Don;t know this for certain about DB2 however.  If the location id has NY inteh center, is it alawys inteh same place? If so then using left, right, substring type functions might be faster than a wildcard at the beginning.  Or if you are going to query this sort of thing frequently, it might be worth pulling that information out into a separate state field on insert or update so that you can more easily query when you are doing selects.

Comment: I tried using substr also , but still the query is not running in prod .. When I run d query it goes on xwait for a long time and below error msg is displayed: unsuccessful execution because DB2 resource limit exceeded . Resource name = ASUTIME , limit = 000000009

Answer (score 0):

If the tabkes are proper indexed and statistics are up-to-date a simple query like this shouldn't cause performance issues.
Check the plan if existing indexes are used and the estimates are correct (totally wrong number probably indicate a statistics problem).

I don't know much about DB2, you can try moving the condition into two Derived Tables, but this shouldn't make a difference for a decent optmizer:

```
Select count(*) 
from
 (
   select adminId, policy
   from Table1
   where T1.location like ('℅NY℅') -- probably T1.location = '℅NY℅'
 ) T1 
join
 (
   select adminId, policy
   from Table2
   where createTimestamp > ( current Timestamp - 1 year)
 ) T2
ON T1.adminId = T2.adminId 
and T1.policy = T2.policy
```

Answer (score -1):

Table 1:

```
AdminId | Policy | LocationId | CreateTimestamp
```

Table 2:

```
AdminId | Policy | CreateTimestamp | Detail1 | Detail2 | ... | Detail50
```

I think your query would be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table2 AS T2
INNER JOIN Table1 AS T1 ON T2.AdminId = T1.AdminId AND T2.Policy = T1.Policy
WHERE T1.Location LIKE ('%NY%') AND T2.CreateTimestamp > DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE())
```

You would still want your LIKE with your wildcards to be in the WHERE clause and you can use DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) to compare to your time stamp to see if the record has been created in the last year.

Comment: The question is about DB2 and the original syntax is perfectly valid in DB2.

Comment: down vote for having data embedded in other data NY.

Comment: Sure, but I really don't understand what you're saying with the "data embedded in other data NY."  Probably because I put the LIKE in the where clause.  An explanation would be fantastic though for my own learning.